# unable to make it work on lazy load modules ngx-bootstrap-product-tour

Tags: lazy-loading, angular5, angular-module

bootstrap-product-tour in my app. and i was imported this module in my app.module,

NgxBootstrapProductTourModule.forRoot(),

and initilized in app.component .ts

But this service is not working in the lazy loaded modules. and not getting any error. Later i tried to import module in lazy loaded module and re initialized in the lazy loaded component with no luck.

can any one help me on how to implement this feature in lazy loaded modules.

Comment: Can you share how did you solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share how did you solve this problem?